# How to select all in primefaces dataTable with liveScroll

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I'm using primefaces v5.3 dataTable with liveScroll="true" and selectionMode="multiple".
Header checkbox selects only visible rows and when i scroll down new rows appear non selected.
I want header checkbox to select all rows: visible and invisible.
Selection of only visible rows is meaningless and useless.
Is it possible to fix?

I tried to add all table data to selection by processing "toggleSelect, rowSelectCheckbox and rowUnselectCheckbox" events. It works on backend, but in UI rows are unselected anyway.

Comment: _"Selection of only visible rows is meaningless and useless. Is it possible to fix?"_ for your usecase maybe. I've never heard this requirement in the last 5 years. And it is a dangerous requirement. Enduser might not expect this (I would not) and act on to many rows. Since it is an uncommon requirement, I doubt there is an easy workaround for this. Downloading the source of the component, checking that and see if you can 'fix' something there is the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this script to replace the original updateData function of primefaces

```
PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.updateData = (function() {

    var cached_function = PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.updateData;
    return function() {
        var reselectAll = (this.selection != undefined && (this.selection[0] === '@all' || this.selection.length === this.getTbody()[0].getElementsByTagName('tr').length);
        var result = cached_function.apply(this, arguments);
        if (reselectAll) {
            this.selectAllRows();
        }
        return result;
    };
})();
```

that will automatically select the new loaded rows on the table(only the ones that are visible on the client side)

Comment: I put this script right in xhtml with my dataTable. But variable table is undefined and this.selection does not have @all value, only numbers 801, 802, ... 819,...

Comment: fixed. Also, selection will have the value '@all' if you use the method  selectAllRows() of the table to select all rows.

Comment: Now it works partly. But i don't understand condition "|| this.selection.length === this.getTbody()[0].getElementsByTagName('tr').length". As for me, it's unnecessary or may be "|| ... === " should be replaced by "&& ... !=" ? And i can't understand how should i call 'selectAllRows();' first time to put '@all' toselection..

Comment: There are two posible values for `this.selection` that will mean that the table has all records selected, `['@all']` and `[**an array with the ids of all selected rows**]` , that condition verify either of them