# How to deselect all in primefaces dataTable with liveScroll

Tags: javascript, primefaces, datatable

I have a case similar to this one [How to select all in primefaces dataTable with liveScroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369335/how-to-select-all-in-primefaces-datatable-with-livescroll?rq=1) and suggested solution for selecting all rows works fine but I have a problem with finding a solution for deselecting all rows. How to solve this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Just tried to add another condition for using unselectAllRows() but it didn't work.